# Should you capitalize "Will" (as in a "Last Will and Testament")?

Tags: capitalization

I had always assumed it would be lowercase, but it seems it's often capitalized. Presumably because it is the title of a document?

If you were to simply call it a "Will" then should it be capitalized or no?

Comment: Is it invoked as a title or as an ordinary noun phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it should not be capitalized, but there is a fashion lately to capitalize it.  The fashion seems to be arising among lawyers, whose capitalization sense seems to have become miscalibrated by the practice of capitalizing specifically defined terms in legal documents.

This may also be the reason behind the change in style in the broader business community, where it is lately popular to capitalize common nouns such as *company, product, sale,* or what have you.  You even occasionally see capitalized verbs.

There is probably also some feeling that capitalizing *will* somehow makes it clearer that it is the *legal document* sense of the word rather than the *desire* or *intention* sense.  But really, there's rarely any such ambiguity, and, frankly, using a capital letter doesn't actually reduce ambiguity.

Outside of an actual will, or another legal document that concerns a specific will, there is no more reason to capitalize *will* than there is to capitalize *contract, affidavit, deposition, instrument, summons,* or any other word denoting any other sort of legal document.

Comment: Sounds like the makings of a good and valuable answer. Any supporting evidence?